# When inserting why does a closure table point to itself

Tags: mysql, sql, closures

Following [Bill Karwin'](http://karwin.blogspot.ca/2010/03/rendering-trees-with-closure-tables.html)s tutorial on closure table, I've never understood why a node needs to point to itself. As an example :

Create table

```
create table closure (
    ancestor int not null,
    descendant int not null,
    primary key (ancestor, descendant),
    foreign key (ancestor) references nodes(node),
    foreign key (descendant) references nodes(node)
);
```

Insert assuming those IDs exists

```
insert into closure (ancestor, descendant) values
    (1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (1,5), (1,6), (1,7),
    (2,2),
    (3,3), (3,4), (3,5),
    (4,4), (4,5),
    (5,5),
    (6,6), (6,7),
    (7,7); // <-- junction to itself?
```

The part I can't really understand is why (1,1) or (2,2) or (3,3) etc... is used for. I tried googling for the answer but I can never seem to find the right key words to use.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Every node in the tree needs to correspond to at least one row in `closure` where its `id` is the `ancestor`. If the node is a leaf, it doesn't have any real descendants, and this degenerate case is represented by pointing the `descendant` to itself.

I believe he creates a self-referencing row for non-leaf nodes so that it's safe to delete the other rows with that `ancestor` -- the node will continue to exist when all descendants are removed.

Comment: . . I think that is only a partial answer, because I suspect the self-reference is needed for all nodes, not just leafs.

Comment: Does negating the self-referencing rows break SELECT or DELETE queries? Also, from all the examples I have found, the closure table has only one main root node. Is it possible to have multiple root nodes?

Comment: Try removing the `(7, 7)` row and see what happens when you run his query that prints all the paths.

Answer (score 1):

**(#1)** As mentioned by Barmar, the self-referencing node allows a leaf node to continue to 'exist' in the closure table if all of its ancestors are deleted.

**(#2)** Similarly, if a subtree is to be moved, there is always a root node when the subtree is 'severed' from its original ancestors.  Without this, I think the process of moving a subtree could be somewhat messier.

**(#3)** Also somewhat similarly, the self-referencing node allows root nodes with no descendants to exist in the closure table.

**(#4)** Having seen some of Bill Karwin's examples, I think it may help you write less-complicated, more-efficient SQL queries, but I'm not expert enough at SQL to actually prove this.

All that said, in the example user1318677 provided, self-referencing records represent 41% of the table, which strikes me as a sizable amount.  If your project doesn't result in **(#1)** or **(#2)** occurring frequently (e.g. a basic forum/comment system), then I think self-referencing nodes are largely redundant data and that you don't necessarily need them.

If anyone else can prove otherwise, I'd love to hear about it.

As a side note, to answer user1318677's question in the comments section: yes, it is possible to have as many root nodes as you like (e.g. 1 root node for each original post to a forum).